# Incomplete final line error but only when running Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the following RODBC command to get some data from a database.

```
SC_blueprint <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT * FROM ae.rdim_sales_chnl_lookup", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This works and I get the data I expect.

I'm using the command within the global.R file of my Shiny App.

When I run the app, the console gives me the following error:

```
Warning in readLines(textConn, encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on ''
```

I've come across incomplete line warning when loading in csv files before but I feel this is different because I can run the code within the global.R and the data is retrieved no problem, but when I launch the Shiny app and the command is executed, it gives me the warning.

While it's a warning and not an error, I have a Shiny element which is a selectizeInput and then doesn't render correctly.